# Bootstrap Time & Date Picker Set Minimum Date

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-4, widget, datetimepicker

****Update** ** - I didn't realise that django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus and Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 were different. It did not dawn on me some of the online tutorials I was trying to follow were given me code that was designed for date pickers other than my own.

I can set a specific maximum date (in this case 6th August 2016) and minimum date (in this case 1st January 2022).

But I cannot get minDate: '-3w' or minDate:0 to work. Below you can see my many attempts.

I looked at http://jsfiddle.net/injulkarnilesh/xNeTe/, http://jsfiddle.net/2CZtV/, https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and have had no luck resolving my issue on my own.

```
$(function () {
    $("#{{ widget.datetimepicker_id }}").datetimepicker({
     

      // minDate: "-3w",
      // minDate: "-3W",
      // minDate: new Date("-3W"),
      // minDate: '-3W',
      // minDate:0
      // minDate:"0",
      // minDate:new Date "0",
      // minDate:new Date ("0"),

      
      // These dates are written in the American Format I think
      minDate: new Date("08/06/2016"),
      maxDate: new Date("01/01/2022"),
    

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try:*

- Clearing the cache or hard reload the page
- If it did not work, check the version of the `datepicker` you are using? Update it to the latest version.